# downloading image with libcurlnet

Tags: c#, winforms, curl, libcurl

everyone.

I've made a class for LibCurlNet using c# winforms I'm having trouble downloading image It is working on most sites however on some sites it only downloads half of the picture not all.

Please Look at the code I posted on below link

[My Class](http://pastebin.com/ieyRhHNT)

and this is how i call the class HTTPGetImage.

```
        HTTP curl = new HTTP();
        curl.CurlInit();

        int status = 0;
        Image myImage = curl.HTTPGetImage(textBox1.Text, ref status);

        if (status == 200)
            pictureBox1.Image = myImage;
```

can anyone please fix my code , or tell me what i'm doing wrong. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if the image is too large and your curl is getting timed out. You are make the execution time unlimited(0 means unlimited) by setting this option.

```
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

Comment: no it does not work , however I found a c code which it does work on all sites without any issues here's the link http://pastebin.com/iEixsFuK can anyone help me convert this code to c# thank you.